# Command Prompt Replace a String in the Middle of Filenames

Tags: windows, cmd, rename

I have a folder with hundreds of files in the following format:

```
20210322 - Filename description.txt
20210321 - Filename description.txt
20210320 - Filename description.txt
20210319 - Filename description.txt
20210318 - Filename description.txt
...
```

Using the Windows Command Prompt, how can I rename them to this format:

```
20210322 Filename description.txt
20210321 Filename description.txt
20210320 Filename description.txt
20210319 Filename description.txt
20210318 Filename description.txt
...
```

In other word replace, replace " - " with " ".

In the past, I've used

```
rename "IMG_*.jpg" "////*.jpg"
```

To remove "IMG_" from the beginning of filenames. I tried to do something similar, but it didn't work:

```
rename "* - *.txt" "*/ /.txt"
```

Comment: The `/`-quirk only works when you have the `/` at the beginning. Use a `for /F` loop: `for /F "tokens=1* delims=- " %I in ('dir /B /A:-D-H-S "* - *.txt"') do ren "I% - %J" "%I %J"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a better solution that works for me. One line, no batch file required. Using Windows Power Shell, enter:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ` Where-Object { $_.Name -match " - " } | ` Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace " - ", " " }
```

The above command will replace the given text in all filenames, including subfolders and subfiles (recursively).

I hope it's able to help someone.

Comment: That command is magical. Works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy enough using a language that is already on supported Windows systems. The `-replace` will remove the `' - '`. When you are satisfied that the files will be renamed correctly, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Rename-Item` command.

```
powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem -Path '.' -Filter '*.txt' |" ^
        "ForEach-Object {" ^
            "Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $($_.Name -replace ' - ',' ') -WhatIf" ^
        "}"
```

It is easier when run from a PowerShell console or as a .ps1 script.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path '.' -Filter '*.txt' |
    ForEach-Object {
        Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $($_.Name -replace ' - ',' ') -WhatIf
    }
```

To get a "one-liner," put the first code example above into a file such as `Do-Rename.bat` saved in a directory mentioned in your PATH variable. Then use a command such as:

```
Do-Rename
```

Comment: Is there a nice one-liner to do this using the "rename" or "ren" command?